# How can I decode a json string in lua nginx?

Tags: nginx, lua

I have nginx configuration file as below:

```
worker_processes  1;
error_log logs/error.log;
events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}
http {
    init_by_lua 'cjson = require("cjson")';
    server {
        listen 8080;

        location / {
        default_type text/html;
        content_by_lua '
            json_text = "{ \"aaa\": \"bar\" }"
            local message = cjson.decode(json_text)
            ngx.say(message)
        ';
        }

    }
}
```

when I access the url http://localhost:8080, I get the error:

```
content_by_lua(nginx.conf:17): in main chunk, client: 127.0.0.1, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost:8080"
2019/11/25 15:03:12 [error] 36979#684497: *2 lua entry thread aborted: runtime error: content_by_lua(nginx.conf:17):2: attempt to call global 'aaa' (a nil value)
```

It complains about call global 'aaa' but what I am doing is just to decode a json string. Do I make anything wrong in the script?

Answer (score 0):

Please don't use `content_by_lua`; even the [manual](https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module#content_by_lua) tells you to use `content_by_lua_block` instead. Most likely your problem results from incorrectly quoting the string; probably because nginx interprets the `\` already and Lua just gets an unescaped `"`.

Also, if you're gonna use quotes inside a string, it's best to stay safe and use `[[` and `]]` or even throw some `=`s in there.

```
        content_by_lua_block {
            json_text = [[{ "aaa": "bar" }]]
            local message = cjson.decode(json_text)
            -- Equivalent to:
            -- local  message = {aaa = "bar"}
            ngx.say(message)
        }
```

Your code won't work anyway though, because `cjson.decode` returns a table, which `ngx.say` won't print (it only prints strings and arrays), so you won't get any output. You could print `message.aaa`, for example, which would print *bar* to the user.